# Laravel 4 : Error in fetching photos from Flickr

Tags: php, laravel-4, flickr

I am using [Anahkiasen/flickering](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/flickering) to get data from flickr in [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

I am new to Laravel. See What I had did to fetching data from Flickr.

In the HomeController I made one method

```
public function flicker()
    {
            $apiKey = "MY API KEY";
            $apiSecret = "MY API SECRET";
            $method = Flickering::handshake($apiKey,$apiSecret);
            $result = Flickering::getResultsOf('photosets.getList', array('user_id' => '116552873@N04', 'per_page' => 20));
                echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";die;
    }
```

This code throws this error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation:

> To start working with Flickering, create a new instance of it like the
>   example underneath. If you set your API credentials in the config
>   file, you don't need to pass any arguments to the constructor as it
>   will automatically fetch your key and secret key from the config
>   files.

You need to create a new instance:

```
$flickering = new Flickering\Flickering($apiKey, $apiSecret);
```

So:

```
$method = $flickering->handshake($apiKey,$apiSecret);
$result = $flickering->getResultsOf('photosets.getList', array(
    'user_id' => '116552873@N04', 
    'per_page' => 20
));
```

If you really want to use the Facade then:

```
Flickering\Facades\Flickering::handshake($apiKey, $apiSecret);
```

I don't recommend this way as there is no benefit in taking this route, the other option allows you to create more testable code.

You should really read the documentation: https://github.com/Anahkiasen/flickering

Edit: Add these lines to the specified configuration section in `config/app.php`.

`providers`

```
'Flickering\FlickeringServiceProvider'
```

`aliases`

```
Flickering' => 'Flickering\Facades\Flickering'
```

It seems that the package is creating an error when creating a new instance of the class.

> Argument 1 passed to Flickering\Flickering::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Container\Container, string given

This could be an issue with Laravel 4.1 on my part.

The Facade is working as expected though:

```
Flickering\Facades\Flickering::handshake("bar", "foo");
```

Comment: Still Not working. I tried to follow as your solutions.

Comment: Thanks. as you said i got the error "Argument 1 passed to Flickering\Flickering::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Container\Container, string given". can you check why it occurs?

Comment: Did you try using the Facade like I said?

Comment: If i used `Flickering\Facades\Flickering::handshake("bar", "foo");` then how can i call to `getResultsOf()` method?

Comment: `Flickering\Facades\Flickering::getResultsOf()` the documentation says that using the Facade uses the same instance.